# The area of circle

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, circles, area

The question is to prove that area of a circle with radius $r$ is $\pi r^2$ using integral. I tried to write $$A=\int\limits_{-r}^{r}2\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\ dx$$
but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Depending on the curriculum where you are, integrals of this form may be treated in _second_ semester calculus, when techniques of integration beyond basic "u-substitution" are discussed.  If you haven't had "trig substitutions" yet, this will seem mysterious. (In first semester, the issue is dodged by just asking students to recognize that the radical represents the expression for a semi-circle with radius $ \ r \ $ centered on the origin.)

Comment: If you are genuinely interested in the topic, I might suggest [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217223/pi-dedekind-cuts-trigonometric-functions-area-of-a-circle) question as further reading.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720935/historic-proof-of-the-area-of-a-circle

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$$2\sqrt{r^2-x^2}=2r\sqrt{1-\left(\frac xr\right)^2}$$

Substitute

$$x=r\sin t\;,\;\;dx=r\cos t\,dt\implies 2r\sqrt{1-\left(\frac xr\right)^2}dx=2r^2\cos^2t\,dt\implies$$

$$\int\limits_{-r}^r2\sqrt{r^2-x^2}dx=2r^2\int\limits_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^2t\,dt=\left.r^2\left(t+\sin t\cos t\right)\right|_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}=\pi r^2$$

Comment: You're missing dt in the "dx = r cos t dt"

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** try a trigonometric substitution.  In particular, try setting $x = r \sin \theta$.

Also, note the identity:
$$
\cos^2 \theta = \frac 12 (1 + \cos(2\theta))
$$

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting solution, not yet mentioned by the other answers, is to use this substitution:

$$
x = r\cos\theta \;\therefore\; \frac{dx}{d\theta} = -r\sin\theta
\;\therefore\; dx = -r\sin\theta \; d\theta
$$
Substituting the integral limits, we have 
$$x = -r \implies -r = r\cos\theta \implies \cos\theta = -1 \implies \theta = \pi$$
$$x = r \implies r = r\cos\theta \implies \cos\theta = 1 \implies \theta = 0$$

With this we can do:
$$
A=-r \int\limits_{\pi}^{0}2\sqrt{r^2-(r\cos\theta)^2} \sin\theta \; d\theta = 
-2r \int\limits_{\pi}^{0}\sqrt{r^2(1 - \cos^2\theta)} \sin\theta \; d\theta = 
$$
$$
-2r \int\limits_{\pi}^{0}\sqrt{r^2\sin^2\theta} \sin\theta \; d\theta = 
-2r \int\limits_{\pi}^{0}r\sin^2\theta \; d\theta = 
-2r^2 \int\limits_{\pi}^{0}\sin^2\theta \; d\theta = 
$$
$$
-2r^2 \int\limits_{\pi}^{0}\frac{1}{2}(1 - \cos(2\theta)) \; d\theta = 
$$

Now we substitute $u = 2\theta \implies \frac{du}{d\theta} = 2 \implies d\theta = \frac{du}{2}$, and limits range from $2\pi$ to $0$:
$$
\frac{-r^2}{2} \int\limits_{2\pi}^{0}(1 - \cos u) \; du = 
\frac{-r^2}{2} (u - \sin u)\Big{|}_{2\pi}^{0} = 
$$
$$
\frac{-r^2}{2} [(0 - \sin 0) - (2\pi - \sin2\pi)] = 
\frac{-r^2}{2} [-2\pi] = \pi r^2
$$