# Is the proof of $\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}=1$ in some high school textbooks circular?

Tags: calculus

I was taught the following proof in high school.

[image]

By constructing triangles with $0<\theta<\pi/2$ and a circle with radius $r$ and by comparing the areas, we have
$$\frac{1}{2}r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta \le \frac{1}{2}r^2\theta\le\frac{1}{2}r^2\tan\theta$$
Hence
$$\cos\theta\le\frac{\theta}{\sin\theta}\le\frac{1}{\cos\theta}$$
Then by squeeze theorem, we have the result.

My question is, the middle term in the above inequality comes from the fact that the area of the circle is $\pi r^2$, which in my textbooks, is later proved by integration. But the integration requires results in calculus which comes from the fact that
$$\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}=1$$

Comment: If that's really how your book proves it, then you are correct that the book's proof is circular. There are other proofs...

Comment: To avoid the problem, we have to prove the 
formula for the area of the cirlce without using trigonometric functions, like the Onion proof. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_of_a_circle#Onion_proof

Comment: look : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1

Comment: Is nobody going to comment on the OP's groanworthy pun?

Comment: Also OP, for what it's worth, a long time ago I asked a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217223/pi-dedekind-cuts-trigonometric-functions-area-of-a-circle). The answer of André Nicolas there shows how the area of the circle can be computed, without any appeal to the trigonometric functions, using clever evaluation of integrals. (Thus, we avoid "circular reasoning", which, once again, is just a terrible pun, OP.)

Comment: @Chris OK Thanks! So that may be the problem of my textbook, in which $\arcsin$ is later used in the proof that the area of a circle is $\pi r^2$.

Comment: @velutluna: you do not need any trigonometric function to prove that the area of a circle is some universal constant multiplied by the squared radius: if the radius of a circle gets multiplied by a positive factor $\lambda$, the area gets multiplied by $\lambda^2$, hence there are no other chances. The only non-trivial part is that such universal constant ($\pi$) is also half the length of a unit circle, but it is possible to prove this statement avoiding any trigonometric function too,

Comment: by just exploiting some rigorous enough definitions of area (of a polygon/of a bounded shape with a smooth boundary) and length (of a polygonal / of a closed, simple, smooth curve).

Comment: The area of circle $A= r \cdot c$ which implies $A = \pi r^2$ should have been proven in geometry.  Then when you get to $\int_-r^r 2\sqrt{r^2-x^2} dx = 2r^2$ you are merely verifying that the result from calculus ties out with the results from classical geometry.

Comment: @Chris I was! Till I saw you'd done the honours. :)

Comment: This is not circular if you have a rigorous theory of area and you *define* $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ for first-quadrant angles as the coordinates of the point $A$ on the unit circle such that the circular sector from $(1,0)$ to $A$ has area $\theta/2$. You also need to prove that a unique such point $A$ exists. Note that very few introductory calculus books have a rigorous theory of area. Knowing what an integral is is not enough for this.

Comment: Most high school textbooks are  not honest with their readers while presenting any proof. Especially when the proof involves anything other than algebraic manipulation of symbols. In case of calculus the situation is pretty worse because most of the proofs depend on theory of real numbers. And it appears that a majority of academic community has decided that high schoolers have no right to learn a proper theory of real numbers. The proof presented above is not circular but rather lacks the rigorous development of areas of plane regions.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)

Answer (score 9):

Usual proofs can be circular, but there is a simple way for proving such inequality.

Let $\theta$ be an acute angle and let $O,A,B,C,D,C'$ as in the following diagram:
[image]

We may show that:

$$ CD \stackrel{(1)}{ \geq }\;\stackrel{\large\frown}{CB}\; \stackrel{(2)}{\geq } CB\;\stackrel{(3)}{\geq} AB $$

$(1)$: The quadrilateral $OCDC'$ and the circle sector delimited by $O,C,C'$ are two convex sets. Since the circle sector is a subset of the quadrilateral, the perimeter of the circle sector is less than the perimeter of the quadrilateral.

$(2)$: the $CB$ segment is the shortest path between $B$ and $C$.

$(3)$ $CAB$ is a right triangle, hence $CB\geq AB$ by the Pythagorean theorem.

In terms of $\theta$ we get:
$$ \tan\theta \geq \theta \geq 2\sin\frac{\theta}{2} \geq \sin\theta $$
for any $\theta\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. Since the involved functions are odd functions the reverse inequality holds over $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},0\right)]$, and $\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}=1$ follows by squeezing.

---

A slightly different approach might be the following one: let us assume $\theta\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. By $(2)$ and $(3)$ we have
$$ \theta \geq 2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\geq \sin\theta $$
hence the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ defined by $a_n = 2^n \sin\frac{\theta}{2^n}$ is increasing and bounded by $\theta$. Any increasing and bounded sequence is convergent, and we actually have $\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n=\theta$ since $\stackrel{\large\frown}{BC}$ is a rectifiable curve and for every $n\geq 1$ the $a_n$ term is the length of a polygonal approximation of $\stackrel{\large\frown}{BC}$ through $2^{n-1}$ equal segments. In particular

$$ \forall \theta\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right), \qquad \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}{\frac{\theta}{2^n}} = 1 $$
and this grants that if the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$ exists, it is $1$. By $\sin x\leq x$ we get $\limsup_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\leq 1$, hence it is enough to show that $\liminf_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\geq 1$. We already know that for any $x$ close enough to the origin the sequence $\frac{\sin x}{x},\frac{\sin(x/2)}{x/2},\frac{\sin(x/4)}{x/4},\ldots$ is convergent to $1$, hence we are done.

Long story short: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ follows from the fact that a circle is a rectifiable curve, and a circle is a rectifiable curve because it is the boundary of a convex, bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The convexity of the disk follows from the triangle inequality: a disk is a closed ball for the euclidean distance.

---

$(1)$ relies on this powerful Lemma:

> **Lemma**. If $A,B$ are convex bounded sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $A\subsetneq B$, the perimeter of $A$ is less than the perimeter of $B$.

**Proof**: by boundedness and convexity, $\partial A$ and $\partial B$ are rectifiable, with lengths $L(A)=\mu(\partial A),\,L(B)=\mu(\partial B)$. Always by convexity, there is some chord in $B$ that does not meet the interior of $A$ (a tangent to $\partial A$ at a smooth point does the job, for instance). Assume that such chord has endpoints $B_1, B_2 \in \partial B$ and perform a cut along $B_1 B_2$: both the area and the perimeter of $B$ decrease, but $B$ remains a bounded convex set enclosing $A$. Since $A$ can be approximated through a sequence of consecutive cuts, $L(A)<L(B)$ follows.

**Late addendum**: this is also a consequence of [Crofton formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crofton_formula).

Comment: Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/a/922970/432081 and the cut-the-knot comments.

Comment: @MikeMathMan: regarding what? To draw the tangent at $B$ is another way for proving that the $BC$ arc is shorter than $CD$, but I am partial to the convexity argument, I find it more elegant and less cumbersome.

Comment: Robjohn's argument is perfectly fine too, but he uses areas and I wanted to use lengths.

Comment: Added a picture that might be helpful...

Comment: While your overall argument is rigorous (+1 for it), I think it is simpler to deal with areas and also show the link between area of sector and length of corresponding arc directly so that one is convinced of the equivalence of both the approaches. I have provided the link between area and length in my answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: that is true, it is much simpler to prove such inequality by comparing areas.

Comment: I added an update in my answer which avoids the convexity argument. Instead it just uses formula for arc-length as an integral.

Answer (score 6):

Step right up here! A high school level demonstration of a fascinating mathematical truth will now be given.
There will be no sleight of hand here - the truth will laid bare for all to witness.
Now, hold on to your seats; for what follows -

No calculus is required!
It isn't even necessary to know the area of circle!.

All that is required for a thrilling experience are the following:

High School Trigonometry and Geometry
Exposure to Archimedes' Method of Deriving the Circumference of a Circle
(see [Business Insider: The beautifully simple method Archimedes used to find the first digits of $\pi$](http://www.businessinsider.com/archimedes-pi-estimation-2014-3))
Exposure to Limits

And now without further ado, introducing the main truth statement of our show,

## $\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}=1\;\;\;\;$ (1)

The following is a demonstration with a sprinkling of statements meant to make it more accessible. The formal part will be highlighted and stands on its own as the proof chain.

The following is the analytical starting point for Archimedes’ circle analysis:

> Proposition 1: Let S and T be two different convex polygon regions in
> $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$.
>  If S ⊂ T, S ≠ T. Then P(S) < P(T), where P
> is the perimeter. 
>   Proof: [Perimeters of Convex Polygons, One within
> the Other \ Cut the Knot](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Geometry/PerimetersOfTwoConvexPolygons.shtml)

Of course Archimedes was not using our coordinate system, but no harm will be done by expressing ancient theorems in a modern framework. Using this Proposition, he proved the following:

> Theorem 2: The ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter
> is $\pi$.

So a circle of radius $1$ had a circumference of $2 \pi$, and instead of degrees, for analysis it is more natural to  measure angles with the [radian system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), so that $90^\circ = 2 \pi /4 = \pi /2$,  $60^\circ = 2 \pi /6 = \pi /3$, etc.

Our proof starts with the following picture:
[image]

This is a picture of chord connecting two points on a circle; the arc length $s$ is equal to the central angle $\theta$ by the definition of a radian.

Here we are interested in comparing the arc length $s(\theta)$ in yellow to the chord length $a(\theta)$ in red. What Archimedes realized is that as the angle gets very small, $a(\theta)$ is a better and better approximation to the arc length $s(\theta) = \theta$. The following provides some insight
[image]

If we bisect a chord, the [sagitta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagitta_(geometry)) of the two new chords are approximately ¼ of the the starting chord ‘distance’ to the circle, $d' \approx d/4$.

In the analysis that follows we will always be working on the unit circle and using radians; also, angles will be positive. It is left for the reader to justify (1) for negative $x$.

We appreciate the technique of quickly determining the arc length of an angle subtended from the center of our unit circle (click [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry/hs-geo-circles/hs-geo-arc-length-deg/v/length-of-an-arc-that-subtends-a-central-angle) for more on this). But for our work here the following is important:

> Theorem 3: The arc length $\theta$ of a circle segment less than or
> equal to $\pi$ can be obtained as as the limit of an increasing
> sequence,
>
> $a(\theta), 2 a(\theta/2), 4 a(\theta/4) ,8 a(\theta/8), \dots $
>
> This sequence is term by term identical to
>
> $2 sin (\theta/ 2 ), 4 sin (\theta/4)  , 8 sin (\theta/ 8) , 16 sin (\theta/16), \dots $ 
>   Proof: This follows from the work of Archimedes
> and that the sine function is the same as the [the half-chord
> function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_trigonometry#Greek_mathematics) used in ancient times. 
> We also have
>   Proposition 4: For any
> $\theta$ in the interval $(0, \pi/2]$, 
>  $0 \lt a/s \lt 1$ 
> Proof: Exercise 
>   Proposition 5: The function $a/s$ is decreasing on
> $(0, \pi/2]$.
>  Proof: Exercise (hint - use Theorem 3).
>
> Proposition 6: As $\theta \gt 0$ approaches $0$, $a/s$ has a limit
> $\le 1$.
>  Proof: Use the above and properties of the real numbers.

Consider the picture

[image]

where $a(\theta)$ is the length of, say, the red chord.

Following Archimedes, $2^n a(\frac{2 \pi}{2^n})$ approaches $2 \pi$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Rearranging terms, this can be stated as follows:

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\, \frac {a(\frac{2\pi}{2^n})} {\frac{2 \pi}{2^n}} = 1\;\;\;\;$ (2)

> Theorem 7: $\lim_{\theta\to 0^+} a/s = 1 \;\;\;\;$ (3)
>  Proof:
> Follows from Proposition 6 and (2).

To motivate what we are going to do, since $a(\theta)=2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$, we can rewrite (2) as

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\, \frac {a(\frac{2\pi}{2^n})} {\frac{2 \pi}{2^n}} = \frac {2 sin(\frac{2\pi}{2^{n+1}})} {\frac{2 \pi}{2^n}} = \frac {sin(\frac{2\pi}{2^{n+1}})} {\frac{2 \pi}{2^{n+1}}} = 1\;\;\;\;$

I stated that you don't need calculus to follow this argument. There is however a technique used there that we need to use here, in a simple way. It is the [change of variable method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_variables).

> Theorem 8: The cosine function is a bijective decreasing mapping from
> $[0, \pi/2] $ to $[0, 1]$.
>  Proof: Exercise.

Using (8) and (13) from [Wolfram: Circular Segment](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html), we see that our function $a/s$ can be expressed as

$\frac{\sqrt{(1-r^2)}}{arcsin(\sqrt{(1-r^2)}}\;\;\;\;\;\;(4)$

If you substitute $r = cos(\psi)$ into (4) you get this final result, proving that (1) is true:

> Theorem 9: $\lim_{\psi\to 0} \frac{\sin \psi}{\psi}=1\;\;\;\;$

We should give Archimedes credit for (1) as it falls out from his circumference calculations. Interestingly, using Theorem 9 you can calculate the area of a circle in a natural way.

---

Note: I would like to thank Jack D'Aurizio who encouraged me to refine my work and to pin things down in a rigorous fashion (no hand waving).

Comment: Reasonable request for proof of $EC\approx\theta$ by @Wojowu now available.

Comment: This is fine, but very far from any geometric intuition. For instance, if we define $\sin z$ as the imaginary part of $e^{iz}$ it is straightforward to prove that $$\sin z=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} $$ for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$, hence $\sin(z)\sim z$ for $z \to 0$. (+1), but this is an analytic proof, not a geometric one. Not entirely, at least.

Comment: *Under continuity assumptions, the limit of a quotient is the quotient of limits* is strictly speaking false, as shown by $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}=1\neq\frac{+\infty}{+\infty},\qquad \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(x)} = 2 \neq \frac{0}{0}.$$

Comment: @jack The main device to get this to work is Proposition 2, but to make things read better I added 'defined quantities'.

Comment: $0$ is a *defined quantity*, so there is still to fix something. The *with a little algebra part* looks handwavy, too. It appears to me that $$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{\frac{2\pi}{2^n}}{EC\left(\frac{2\pi}{2^n}\right)} = 1 $$ is equivalent to the claim $\sin\theta\sim\theta$ for $\theta\to 0$.

Comment: Since $EC(\theta)=2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$.

Comment: @Jack - uh 0/0 is undefined. Also try this. Let n=3 so you r breaking the circle 45 degree arcs. EC is one side of that octagon. Let n go to infinity.

Comment: I agree that $\lim_{\theta\to 0^+}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}=1$ does not come unexpected, but if we have to prove it, we have to prove it, and simply replacing $\theta$ with $\frac{\theta}{2^M}$ is not a proof by itself, it is just a change of variable.

Comment: A picture does not fix such issue. You are just performing a change of variable and assuming the claim.

Comment: I've thought about this a great amount of time. I wonder how much time you spent looking it over.  It appears not much time, with the rapid fire comments.

Comment: I raised a point and you added a picture that does not solve the issue, so there isn't much to think about it. Are you getting the matter I talk about?

Comment: You are welcome to edit my post, put index numbers by all the claims, and then in a comment ask my to justify any claim. I will put the detail in the answer post. Getting late now. Have a good night.

Comment: +1. Nice improvement. Once the question was about a high school level, in my answer I tried use geometric intuition without beeing too rigorous.

Comment: Thanks @jack for putting in the details.

Comment: Your proposed fix at the end is correct and is really a novel approach to proving the fundamental limit formula $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin x} {x} =1$. +1

Comment: @jack - paramanand-singh liked your fix. And dyadic rationals is not that scary! We can also fix things up by showing that $sin(x) \lt x$ (for the advanced high school student).

Answer (score 4):

A comment on the geometry:

From the fact that
a straight line 
is the shortest distance
between two points,
I can see why
$\sin(\theta)
\le \theta$.

But,
considering that the arc is curved,
I do not see how we can deduce
from the drawing that
$\theta
\le \tan(\theta)$.
How do we know that
the arc doesn't wiggle enough
so that
the opposite inequality occurs?

Comment: If $A,B$ are two convex sets and $A\subseteq B$, then $\mu(\partial A)\leq \mu(\partial B)$, that's *how*.

Comment: That seems fairly advanced. But then, to do this rigorously is advanced. Thanks, Jack.

Comment: In this case, a rather obvious differentiable contraction maps the segment $\tan \theta$ to $\theta$. (A little geometry is needed to show it's indeed a contraction.) For any reasonable definition of arc length, this implies $\theta \le \tan\theta$. This may be more elementary than @JackD'Aurizio 's comment.

Comment: @Olivier: but my comment is elementary, too. Assume that $A,B$ are two convex bounded sets and $A\subsetneq B$. Then $\partial A$ and $\partial B$ are rectifiable, with lengths $L(A)=\mu(\partial A),\,L(B)=\mu(\partial B)$. By convexity, there is some chord in $B$ that lies outside $A$. Assume that such chord has endpoints $B_1, B_2$ and $A$ lies on the left of such chord: by replacing the $B_1 B_2$ arc on the right of the $B_1 B_2$ chord with the chord, the perimeter of $B$ decreases, but $B$ continues to be a closed convex set containing $A$. We may approximate $A$ through a sequence of cuts

Comment: hence it follows that $L(A)<L(B)$ as wanted. This is indeed an elementary and powerful Lemma, so why not to use it?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks for sharing the details. I thought there might be some subtleties to it, but your explanation is convincing.

Comment: @Olivier: feel free to point them out in my answer, I have just appended such Lemma with the proof I sketched a minute ago.

Comment: Marty, certainly the area ($\frac12 \theta$) of the sector of the unit circle is less than the area ($\frac12 \tan(\theta)$) of the triangle.  See Paramanand's answer (@paramanandsingh) on this page to see that the area is one-half the arc length.

Answer (score 3):

This has been discussed earlier and I will post link if I find it. To simplify the proof we can just work with circle of unit radius. And instead of dealing with arc lengths we deal with area of sectors. This avoids the problem of dealing with comparison of arc lengths which requires notions of convexity of curves (like done in Jack d'Aurizio's answer here).

The following theorem holds:

> If $L$ is the length of an arc of unit circle and $A$ the area of corresponding sector then $L=2A$.

The proof follows *not via the use of circular functions as many believe* but simply via integration by parts. Note that we have $$\int_{a} ^{1}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\,dx=-\frac{a\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$$ or $$\int_{a}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}=2\left(\frac{a\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}{2}+\int_{a}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\,dx\right)$$ which is the desired relation $L=2A$ for an arc with end points $(1,0)$ and $(a, \sqrt{1-a^{2}})$ (with $a\in(0,1)$) of the unit circle. Once we have this relation we immediately get the following inequality (as mentioned in question) via comparison of areas: $$\sin\theta<\theta<\tan\theta$$ for all $\theta\in(0,\pi/2)$.

---

**Update**: If one translates the geometrical definition into analysis we get the the following link between $x$ and $\sin x$ which is valid for $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$: $$x=\int_{0}^{\sin x} \frac{dt} {\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}$$ and dealing with positive values of $x$ we see that the integrand in the integral on right of above equation lies between $1$ and $1/\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}x}$ and thus we get the inequalities $$\sin x< x< \frac{\sin x} {\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}x}}=\tan x$$ so all that argument from geometry about arc-length of convex curves is not needed. The traditional proof avoids usage of direct formula for length of arc of a circle in terms of integrals and the argument becomes unnecessarily complex. This is done because the proof is presented at a stage when one is learning limits and is totally unaware of the concept of an integral.

Comment: (+1) I used a similar approach [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1/2046827#2046827) to show that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

[image]

For a high school level you can use the lenght of the arc.

$$\sin \theta \le\theta\le \tan \theta\to 1\le \frac{\theta}{\sin \theta}\le \frac{1}{\cos \theta}$$

In order to see that, we can use a know result from Euclidian Geometry:

*Theorem: In a triangle the bigger angle is always apposite to the bigger side.*

So, from the right triangle $ACE$ we get

$$\sin \theta \le EC$$

and from the obtuse triangle $EFC$ we get

$$EC\le \tan \theta$$

and then

$$\sin \theta \le EC\le \tan \theta$$

when $\theta $ is very small we have $EC \approx \theta$.

Comment: I can't see the lengths satisfies your inequality in a trial way.

Comment: Thank you! But I still can't see why your inequality holds. I can see $\sin \theta < \tan \theta$ with no problem. But what about the arc length?

Comment: I can see the arc length is $\theta$ (and in fact $\theta$ needs not be small). But how to prove that $\sin\theta \le EC \le \tan\theta$?

Comment: @velutluna: new update.

Comment: The circle has radius 1. So sin is AE

Comment: The $EC\approx\theta$ would require explanation IMO. What does it mean and why is it true?

Comment: @arnaldo - couldn't resist. Filled in some stuff to make your answer bullet proof.

Comment: @MikeMathMan: what have you filled in? In the current state, this answer is not bullet-proof at all - the last statement ($EC\approx \theta$) is more or less equivalent to the original problem ($\sin\theta\sim\theta$).

Comment: The hard part is to actually prove that the $EC$ **arc** is shorter than $CF$.

Comment: @jack   Did you see my answer?