# How was the area formula for a circle ($A = \pi r^2$) derived before the introduction of calculus?

Tags: geometry, circles, area

How did mathematicians prior to the coming of calculus derive the area of the circle from scratch, without the use of calculus?

The area, $A$, of a circle is $\pi r^2$. Given radius $r$, diameter $d$ and circumference $c$, by definition, $\pi := \frac cd$.

Comment: 'how did they" — I have no idea how, but this malicious group of people surely was not doing math, because you cannot even define area without some bits of calculus.

Comment: You can't rigorously prove it without calculus, but you can give pretty convincing heuristic arguments. See, for instance, [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_of_a_circle) for some examples.

Comment: @GiantLeap You might want to watch 3Blue1Brown's [video](https://youtu.be/WUvTyaaNkzM?t=1m30s) on the intuition behind the formula.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to define the area of plane figures bounded by straight lines without calculus - break them up into triangles. It is also quite easy (by using polygonal approximations to the circle) to show that if it is assumed that the area exists, it scales as $r^2$. You should note that it is at least as difficult to decide the arc length of a curve (and hence $C$) as it is to define Area enclosed by a curve ($A$). The radius and diameter are straight lines.

Comment: I do not know why someone edited the question to change capital letters to lower case - when I had just put a comment using capitals where OP had used capitals. It didn't seem necessary and wasn't helpful.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Area_of_Circle/Proof_3, this claims to prove the formula using some simple geometry and proof by contradiction (no calculus involved).

Comment: @Sil: That proof implicitly assumes that circumferences and areas are well-defined quantities which satisfy certain properties (e.g., a circular arc joining any two points is longer than a line segment joining those two points). This all seems intuitively plausible, but a rigorous justification of it would involve calculus.

Comment: [Episode 7: Integration - The Mechanical Universe](https://youtu.be/w6ynSbzPhjc?t=421)

Comment: @Sil this should be the answer.

Comment: @xsnl that seems backwards to me. At least from the Riemann formulatiom of of integrals, don't we need to know the area of a rectangle before we can use a sum of many rectangles to compute an  area of a function?

Comment: @xsnl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)

Comment: @xsnl yeah you can. You can express it as weight rather than space.

Comment: @Tyberius - (s)he meant area in general, not area of rectangles. It is easy enough to define area for planar figures with piece-wise linear boundaries without calculus. But as soon as you allow some curvature (as in a circle), you need some sort of limiting process (variations abound - it doesn't have to be integration), which can be considered to be calculus.

Comment: @Sentinel - and how are you defining "weight"? This is mathematics, not physics we are talking about.

Comment: Once it was known that there was a constant ratio between circmfererece and diameter, it was as a logical next step to easily find area on that basis   The area is made of large numver of tiny triangles or wedges..  $ \Sigma \frac12  p \cdot r = P  \cdot r /2 = \pi r^2 $

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There's an interesting method using which you can approximately find the area. Split up the circle into many small sectors, and arrange them as a parallelogram as shown in the image (from wikipedia)

[image]

The higher the number of sectors you take, the more it tends to a parallelogram, with one of it’s height the radius $r$, and the other side half the circumference $\pi r$. Thus, its area tends to $\pi r \cdot r = \pi r^2$

Comment: Is this not just integration in disguise?

Comment: @HBeel well, you do split it up into very-small approximate triangles which we then sum up, so yeah it can be interpreted as a form of integration. Nonetheless, you can see through the machinery and understand what is happening here more intuitively.

Comment: Upvoted because this is the same "intuitive" explanation taught to me as a schoolkid. The most tricky bit is that takes a fair bit of intuition (or at least hand-waving) to see that the "sort-of parallelogram" becomes a rectangle at the limit.

Comment: @HBeel Any way of doing this will be integration in disguise.

Comment: but you have to know the circumference, thus $\pi$ first

Comment: @lisyarus so the answer should be "mathematicians didn't derive the area of a circle without calculus". I'm confused why this is the top answer. While interesting and correct it doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: @HBeel It depends on what do we call integration. The technique of taking the limit of approximating sums was known long before the rigorous study of integration began.

Comment: This is how I "learned" it in maybe ~3rd grade and I explicitly remember finding it to be complete nonsense that it looks like a rectangle. Let alone that the concept of a "limit" is hard enough to gasp: I didn't even see at all why the curves on the sectors should ever disappear. So I didn't find this convincing at all.

Comment: @lisyarus I would say that this does not matter: it is still integration. Most of the classical tools of mathematics were used in some form before they were studied systematically and/or rigorously. After all, you need to see several examples of something before you are motivated to study it in depth.

Comment: @Mehrdad Were you able to find any more justification for it being a rectangle, or does it just come down to "think about it more closely"?

Comment: @Ovi: It's "obvious" to me now, so I guess you could say it's the latter. I've never bothered to try but I think it shouldn't be hard to prove that the curvature disappears fast enough...

Comment: What evidence is there that this answer is responsive to "How did mathematicians prior to the coming of calculus derive the area of the circle from scratch"?  Do you have historical evidence that this method was used?

Comment: As @EricTowers implies, this is not the answer to the question.

Comment: Do you know that that actually is the method that was used before the introduction of calculus? Maybe it wasn't even done at all before the introduction of calculus.

Answer (score 46):

Calculus depends on the concept of a limit, and does apply that to the problem of determining the area of a curved object. But the concept of a limit and the ability to reason about the area of a curved object using that concept existed before Calculus.

As far as recorded history is concerned, Archimedes was the first to derive $A = \pi r^2$. Though he didn't call it $\pi$, I think we can still say this is the answer to your question. His proof depends on the concept of a limit. He showed that, given a circle, with radius $r$ and circumference $c$, the area of that circle can't be more than that of a triangle with height $r$ and base $c$, and that it can't be less than the area of that triangle either. He did this by examining the area of polygons with an increasing number of sides, both inside the circle and outside the circle. This involved the concept of a limit and calculating area, which FEELS like calculus, but isn't.

Polygons with increasing number of sides inside:
[image]
Polygons with increasing number of sides outside:
[image]

Comment: So how do we define Calculus?  I would say that any infinitesimal argument is the use of Calculus.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe If you define calculus as using limits to calculate an area, then Archimedes invented it instead of Newton or Leibniz. Calculus is much more than that, and it became its own field once we discovered that the derivative of the area function was the original function.

Comment: @DeNovo I know about this.  But again: How to define Calculus properly? Archimedes used integration, but no derivatives.

Comment: This understates the subtlety of Archimedes' proof. It not only involves using limits to calculate areas (even Euclid did that!), but also requires a convexity argument which — if fully justified for curved figures —  will end up using some notion of tangent line. I don't know that delineating whether something is or is not calculus is particularly productive, but Archimedes is a lot closer to doing calculus than you're giving him credit for.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe If the term *calculus* is ambiguous, you might make a distinction between *infinitesimals* and *analysis* or *standard analysis*.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe How to define calculus properly is an entire other question (and I suspect off topic for this site, since it's probably a matter of opinion)

Answer (score 35):

Euclid initiates this is [Book XII, Prop. 2.](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookXII/propXII2.html), showing indirectly that there is a constant of proportionality between the area of a circle and its diameter.  He does this by showing that the area of two circles goes as the square of their diameters, which forces this constant of proportionality between, in the Question's notation, $A$ and $r^2$.  Lets call that constant $p$: $A = p r^2$.  So Euclid shows that $p$ exists, but does not show that $p$ is related to the ratio of the length of the circumference to that of the diameter.

The [preceding proposition](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookXII/propXII1.html) in that book, that the areas of similar polygons inscribed in circles are in the same ratio as the squares of the diameters of the circles, gives us a method to approximate $p$ from below, by using sequences of polygons that cover more and more of the circle.  Archimedes uses this method (as well as the result that a circumscribed polygon contains all the area of the circle) to bound $p$ in his [Measurement of a Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_of_a_Circle).  But first, he uses these facts about inscribed and circumscribed polygons to show $p = \pi$.

His first proposition is the result you ask about: The area of a circle is equal to the area of a right triangle with one leg having the length of the radius and the other leg having the length of the circumference.  That is, using the definition you give that the circumference is $\pi$ times the diameter and also that the diameter is twice the radius, 
$$ A = \frac{1}{2} \cdot r \cdot C = \frac{1}{2} \cdot r \cdot (\pi \cdot 2r) = \pi r^2  \text{,}  $$
so $p = \pi$.

Archimedes proves this result by the method of exhaustion.  It is common to claim that this method is elementary calculus, but that isn't entirely correct.  As it is used here (and in many other places), it is an application of [trichotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics)) to the [completeness of the reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers#Nested_intervals_theorem) and is a method more commonly used in advanced calculus and real analysis.  Archimedes observes that if the area of the triangle is not the area of the circle, it must be either greater or less than the area of the circle.  [He shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_of_a_circle#Historical_arguments) it cannot be greater, then that it cannot be less.  Therefore, the area of the triangle is the same as the area of the circle.

(Using completeness of the reals, one would phrase this as: for all $\varepsilon >0$, the area of the triangle differs from the area of the circle by less than $\varepsilon$, so is the same as the area of the circle.  If we imagine a shrinking sequence of $\varepsilon$s, this gives the nested sequence of intervals for the completeness link above.)

Answer (score 15):

Another way to derive the formula for the area of a circle is by decomposing it into several concentric rings (annuli) to form a "triangle" as seen in the below diagram.  As the width of the concentric rings approach zero, it forms a triangle of base circumference ($C$ = $\pi$$d$) and height $r$.
[image: decomposing a circle into concentric rings diagram]

Since we know the area of a triangle is $\frac{bh}{2}$, by substitution $$\frac{\pi d\cdot r}{2}$$
Since $d$ = 2$r$, $$A = \frac{\pi \cdot 2r\cdot r}{2} \rightarrow A = \frac{\pi \cdot 2r^2}{2} \rightarrow A = \pi \cdot r^2$$.

Comment: +1, this is what I was trying to say in my badly worded answer...

Answer (score 14):

It is easy to go from the area of a triangle to the area of a regular polygon (one whose sides all
have the same length and whose angles all have the same measure) by breaking the polygon into
triangles and summing the areas of the triangles. But we need to first review the formula for the area of a polygon for reference.
It can be shown that every regular polygon can be inscribed in a circle. If we draw a perpendicular line from the center of the circle to any side of the inscribed polygon, that line is called
an apothem. It is a fact
that the area of a regular polygon is $1/2ap$ where $a$ is the apothem and $p$ is the perimeter of the
polygon. It is also a fact that as the number of sides of the inscribed
regular polygons increases, the lengths of the apothems of the polygons approach the radius of the
 circle. [image]

[image]

Comment: Archimedes did that for  polygons inscribed and circumscribed into a same circle, by adopting [the Exhaustion Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_exhaustion)

Comment: Where did the pictures comes from?

Comment: This link https://www.veritasprep.com/blog/2013/07/quarter-wit-quarter-wisdom-questions-on-polygons-inscribed-in-circles/

Comment: This one https://m.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Area-of-a-Polygon?amp=1

Comment: I would upvote too if the op didn't specify a timeframe 

Comment: So, why are you not crediting the origin of the images?

Answer (score 14):

The *area* is very much a concept belonging to Calculus. In this regard *to find the area of something without using Calculus* is almost an oxymoron, but we can have an intuitive (and not too general) notion of area based on the following points:

1. Any rectangle deserves an area (i.e. it is a measurable set) and the area of a rectangle $R$ with side lengths $a,b,a,b$ is $\mu(R)=ab$;
2. Isometric measurable sets have the same area and if a line splits some measurable set $R$ into two components $R_1,R_2$ then $R_1,R_2$ are measurable and $\mu(R_1)+\mu(R_2)=\mu(R)$. This fixes the area of parallelograms, triangles, bounded polygons;
3. Not every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a polygon, so we want to extend the notion of measurability in the following way: given $K$, a compact and connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, we define $\mathcal{I}$ as the family of polygons contained in $K$, $\mathcal{E}$ as the family of polygons containing $K$. If
   $$ \sup_{P\in\mathcal{I}} \mu(P) = \inf_{P\in\mathcal{E}}\mu(P) = L $$
   we say that $K$ is measurable and define its area as $\mu(K)=L$.

Notice that 1.,2.,3. do not allow to measure unbounded sets like $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x\geq 0, 0\leq y\leq\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\}$ 
or subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with countable connected components, like $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{(x,y): (x-n)^2+y^2\leq \frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\}$.
Still we may use this naive notion of area to compute the area of the unit circle. By considering the regular polygons in $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{E}$ we have
$$ \mu\left(\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 1\right) = \sup_{n\geq 3}n\cdot\sin\frac{\pi}{n} = \inf_{n\geq 3}n\cdot\tan\frac{\pi}{n}=\pi $$
hence the area of the unit circle is just half the length of its boundary and $\pi\in(3,4)$ follows from the fact that

> If $A,B$ are two convex, bounded sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $A\subsetneq B$, the length of $\partial A$ is less than the length of $\partial B$. (see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2320028/44121))

An Archimedean-like geometric approach for the numerical approximation of $\pi$ is the following: a circle with radius $1$ can be decomposed as the union of an octagon with side length $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$ and eight [circular segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment). Such segments can be approximated by parabolic segments, whose area is simply $\frac{2}{3}\text{base}\cdot\text{height}$. The parabolic segments are slightly smaller than the corresponding circle segments, hence the following construction

[image]

leads to the lower bound 
$$\pi > \frac{16}{3}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}-\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{2}= 3.13914757\ldots$$
whose accuracy is comparable with the actual Archimedean approximation $\pi\leq\frac{22}{7}$. The parabolic method applied to the regular dodecagon leads to the nice bound
$$ \pi > 4\sqrt{6}-4\sqrt{2}-1 = 3.1411\ldots $$
which also explains the proximity between $\pi$ and $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$.

A broader notion of *area* comes from defining the Riemann/Lebesgue integral and defining the area of $K\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ as
$$ \mu(K) = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\mathbb{1}_K(x,y)\,dx\,dy $$
provided that the RHS makes sense. 1,2,3 are fulfilled, and this also allows us to measure the previous troubling sets. Additionally, this gives us new ways for approximating 
$$\pi=4\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx = 6\arcsin\frac{1}{2} = 3\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{16^n(2n+1)}=3+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{9}{640}+\left(0\leq\varepsilon\leq 3\cdot 10^{-3}\right) $$
also through
$$ \frac{1}{5\cdot 4^8}\approx\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^8(1-x)^8}{1+x^2}\,dx=4\pi-\frac{188684}{15015}.$$

---

Improving the answer: why is it enough to study the *unit* circle? Because a circle is highly symmetric, os by applying a dilation with factor $\lambda>0$ the area is multiplied by $\lambda^2$ and the length of the boundary is multiplied by $\lambda$ (the fundamental property of affine maps is that they preserve the ratio of areas). In particular if the area of the unit circle is $\beth$, the area of a circle with radius $R$ is $\beth R^2$.

How is this related with the length of the boundary? Through convexity. If we consider the annulus between two concentric circles with radii $R$ and $R+\varepsilon$, the area of the annulus divided by $\varepsilon$ tends to the length of the boundary of the inner circle as $\varepsilon\to 0^+$. In particular if $\beth R^2$ is the area of the circle with radius $R$, the length of its boundary is given by 
$$ \frac{d}{dR}\beth R^2 = \color{red}{2\beth}R.$$

Comment: Euclid is already comparing areas in Book I, Prop. 34.  (By congruence, so, as per normal, shows two things are the same without measuring either of them.)  Prop. 35 compares (barely) different objects, by subtracting a common subobject from two congruent objects to yield two non-congruent objects with the same "area" (whatever that is).  So Euclid has your items 1 and 2 in Book I (with your 1 generalized to parallelograms).

Comment: When you switch to approximating $\pi$, you skip right past OP's question: why is the constant of proportionality of areas the same as the constant of proportionality of circumferences?

Comment: I agree that there is *a* constant of proportionality, which is what you and Euclid show.  Why is it the *same* constant, which is what the OP asks?

Comment: @EricTowers: I have updated my answer by including clearer explanations at the end.

Comment: The clearer explanation at the end is not responsive to OP's "How did mathematicians prior to the coming of calculus derive the area of the circle from scratch, without the use of calculus?"

Comment: @EricTowers: it is responsive. They didn't, they just used a pre-calculus notion of area.

Comment: The octogon diagram makes this the most understandable answer for the layman

Answer (score 9):

Monte Carlo method.

Pick a random x/y by throwing lots of dice. Ensure the points fall randomly on a square of width equal to circle's diameter. Repeat many times, or until satisfied, very bored, or until Happy Hour and Martinis are on the Casino (hence 'Monte Carlo' method. It is just about April 1st).

Take the ratio of the points that fall in the circle to those that fall outside. Note how as the number of random points increases, the ratio converges on a certain amount.

Comment: Good answer, but I doubt ancient mathematicians used Montecarlo method to derive the area

Comment: I would up-vote too if the op didn't specify a time frame. Good answer.

Comment: no, that is nonsense. there is no evidence that "mathematicians prior to the coming of calculus derive the area of the circle" n this way.

Comment: In a similar fashion, you could also throw sticks on stripes. See [Buffon's needle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle).

Comment: @Joonas Ilmavirta Excellent! See this Buffon, who was practically a caveman, was able to guess PI using nothing more than zebra skin and a whalebone needle.

Comment: The question specifically asks how mathematicians worked out the area of a circle before the introduction of calculus.  This derivation came later, and is therefore not an answer to the question.

Comment: The question in the title asks how to derive the area of a circle without calculus, which this question does.  I took the the specification "before calculus" in the body to mean "without calculus", which is closer to OP's intent.  Upvoted!

Comment: Yeah most of the other answers don't address the time aspect either. If I was a caveman I would just make an arrangement of square and circle of equal diameter, fill them with water and compare the weights. Guessing pi would have been trivial, even by say comparing weights of square and round objects made from molten metals etc. Counting beans etc. A monte Carlo approach would have been intuitive.

Comment: The title is not the question, it is a marker/pointer to help find it more easily. If it doesn't match the body, it should be edited, not used to justify posts NAA.

Answer (score 4):

Since two circles are similar, their areas are proportional to the squares of their radii. Now the area of a circle with radius $1$ is the proportional factor, just call it $\pi$.

Addendum.  If you insist in the usual definition of $\pi$, i. e., the ratio of circumference to diameter, I doubt there will be no connection to my approach without an infinitesimal argument, that is calculus.

One imho nice approach would be to define a discrete $\pi_n$ for every regular $n$-gon, namely $\pi_n:=n\cdot\tan(\pi/n)$, which is the ratio of the $n$-gon’s circumference to its diameter. (Here the radius $r_n$ is defined by 
the distance of the $n$-gon’s center to one of its sides.)

In that case the area $A_n=\pi_n\cdot r_n^2$ and the circumference is $2\pi_n\cdot r_n$.

From here we see that if the proportional factor for the area is $\pi_n$, the factor for the circumference $2\pi_n$.  That’s true for $n$-gons from above.

But how to show that without calculus for circles?

I know that there are some curves which lengths may be calculated purely algebraic, such as Neil’s parabola $t\mapsto(t^2,t^3)$.  But I don’t know an algebraic  way for the circle.  Since a purely algebraic rectification was thought impossible since Aristotle, I presume there is none for the circle.

Comment: That is not how $\pi$ is usually defined.

Comment: But how to prove that this is the same pi as that defined in the OP as c/d?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I agree, but the OP wants a derivation of the circle’s area without  calculus, and I gave one.

Comment: This is not a very satisfactory derivation, mainly because that's not how $\pi$ is commonly defined based on circular geometry. It is imperative that one go from the $\pi = \frac cd$ definition to $A = \pi r^2$, in my opinion.'

Comment: In my course Calculus 1, $\pi$ was defined as the smallest positive zero of $\sin$, which was defined as a power series.  Now what do you call “commmonly defined”?  See also my addendum, please.

Comment: I'm more interested in how you came about the original claim, i.e. that two circles being similar (how is this defined?) implies that the area is proportional to the square of the radius. Can you show a proof for that which doesn't require calculus?

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry), please.

Comment: The essential property here is stated without proof. Where can I find a proof of this fact for general areas (not polygons)?

Comment: @AlexanderJ93: Euclid XII.2 proves it for circles. (But he does use a limiting argument...)

Comment: Would at least one of the downvoters explain their reason to do so, please?

Answer (score 4):

1. Get two large sheets of papyrus with uniform thickness
2. Cut a circle of unit radius from one, and a unit square from the other
3. Measure the weight of each shape
4. From their ratio you get the area
   of the circle

Comment: BTW, this method is very similar to the one posted by DRPR.

Answer (score 2):

By trial and error and by numerical approximations. The ancient mathematicians (Babylonians, 1800 BC) tried to square a circle (approximating the area of circle with a square, constructing a square with the same area as a circle, proved impossible in 1882 AD), to calculate $\sqrt{2}$, $\pi$, etc.

The precise calculation of the area of circle requires an infinitesimal analysis (calculus).

Answer (score 1):

I am going to use a non conventional method here:-

If you stack circles on top of circles ,  it forms a cylinder of considerable height.

Now the volume of this cylinder is equal to
 $Vol\, (cylinder) =A*H   \quad\\where\, A=\text{Area of the circle (still unknown)}\\ \text{and H = height of the cylinder that you have created}  $

Now the volume of the cylinder is equal to  the increase of liquid level when the e object is immersed in the liquid (usually water).(Application of  Archimedes principle) .This is how you get the volume of the cylinder.

Divide the volume by $H(\text{measurable quantity})$ and you get the Area.

To get the formula of the area of the circle you may have to use numerical methods.

Comment: This isn't just non-conventional, it's nonsensical. A circle has zero volume. Make an infinite stack of them and it's still a height of zero.

Comment: @Nij Take 10 coins and stack them up on top of each other . i am sure you will get certain height .Then divide the volume you get with that height . If you dont get the area of the circle/base of the cylinder , then what do you get?

Comment: Coins are already a cylinder, so you should have just measured one of them already. They're not circles which have zero volume.

Comment: Do you think that just because Archimedes took a bath one time in his life, he used water to solve math problems?  He was a troublemaker who was properly disposed of by the Roman army.  What is interesting is how you can tilt the cylinder to get it exactly half full.

Comment: @richard1941 You can use any fluid/ liquid , not necessarily water

Comment: The original question was "How did mathematicians prior to the coming of calculus ...". Well, we are talking about time before Arkhimedes then. The profession mathematician didn't exist, all its practitioners were philosophers, engineers etc. And their concepts were much less abstract than ours. So it's plausible to say that they didn't differentiate the concept of area from the material whose area they were measuring. So from a historical point of view, it's a perfectly correct answer IMO. How would a modern mathematician approach this problem, is a different question entirely.